# SQL script: new column 1 if value exist in other column else 0

Tags: sql, hana

I have first table `T1` in SAP HANA DB like this:

```
T1
----------------------------
| key | value | date       |
----------------------------
| 1   |  A    | 01-02-2018 |
| 2   |  B    | 01-03-2017 |
| 3   |  C    | 01-02-2017 |
| 4   |  D    | 01-02-2018 |
----------------------------
```

And the other table T2:

```
T2
---------------------
| value | date       |
----------------------
|  B    | 01-02-2017 |
|  B    | 01-05-2017 |
|  D    | 01-02-2019 |
----------------------
```

I need to add to `T1` new column as indicator with value '1' if `T1.value` exists in `T2.value` and `T2.date < T1.date` for this value, else '0'. I can only use select query or SQL script for this, with no insert or update statements.

Expected result:

```
----------------------------------------
| key | value | date        | indicator |
----------------------------------------
| 1   |  A    | 01-02-2018  | 0         |
| 2   |  B    | 01-03-2017  | 1         |
| 3   |  C    | 01-02-2017  | 0         |
| 4   |  D    | 01-02-2018  | 0         |
-----------------------------------------
```

Please, help with query or script on HANA SQL.

Comment: Happy to help anytime. Did you try to write some sql? Hint: Look for `CASE` clause in SQL

Answer (score 3):

> I need to add to T1 new column as indicator with value '1' if T1.value
>   exists in T2.value and T2.date < T1.date for this value, else '0'.

This is solved with `EXISTS`:

```
select 
  t1.*,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from t2 
      where value = t1.value and date < t1.date
    ) then '1'
    else '0'
  end indicator
from t1
```

Comment: `exists` is the right solution.  I upvoted, but I strongly recommend that *all* columns be qualified with the appropriate table alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `correlated subquery`

```
select T1.*, 
       ( select sign(count(1)) from T2 where T2.date < T1.date and T2.value = T1.value )
       as indicator
  from T1;
```

*The* `sign()` *function returns 1 provided there's at least one row satisfying the condition*

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/VKAIM29852)</kbd>

Comment: @forpas thanks, I need to add `sign()` function also.